# How to deploy nodeJs app from Bitbucket to Azure

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, bitbucket-pipelines

Bitbucket has from some time ago availability of [Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) and I've been strugling, not from the Bitbucket part, but the Azure part as I can't find an easy way to deploy.

in my BitBucket, I have a `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` with

```
image: node:8.9.4

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build and test
        caches:
          - node
        script: # install packages and run tests
          - npm install
          - npm test
    - step:
        name: Deploy to Azure
        script:
          - git push https://$AZURE_LOGIN:$AZURE_PASSWORD@$AZURE_APP_NAME.scm.azurewebsites.net/$AZURE_APP_NAME.git master
```

and all works well from BB part, issue is that the code sent to Azure, from that command line is the application source, and I can't find an easy way to tell Azure to run `npm install` and I end up with **Internal Server Error** where a package was not found when I try to run the website after being deployed ...

I've then created a VSTS account to configure **Continuous Delivery** in both parts... the option CD in Azure portal as well create a pipeline in VSTS...

---

(through Azure portal directly)
[image]

---

(manually from VSTS)
[image]

---

My question is simple... in order to avoid anything from Azure portal (seems to complicate at the moment, or it's just me as I'm more used to work with AWS and Heroku), is there a way to actually deploy from BitBucket automagically?

Answer (score 0):

> How to deploy nodeJs app from Bitbucket to Azure

A simple solution is to use Continuous Deployment,
 this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-continuous-deployment#overview) has details on how to set up, basically

1. you choose where your repository lives:
   [image]
2. every time you update your source repo, the change will get pushed to Azure
3. Azure will then build the new website, which in your case (node environment), [`npm install` will run automatically](https://github.com/projectkudu/KuduScript/blob/master/lib/templates/deploy.batch.node.template#L51-L57)

I am not sure if you need VSTS, since I imagine that your workflow is something like this (based on my assumption of how CI works)

1. create pull request, which triggers your bit-bucket pipeline
2. once build and tests are all successful, you merge your commit
3. with continuous deployment, Azure will get noticed and update your website

Comment: I found out that the `git push azure.git` will perform `npm install` as well, so you don't need any VSTS either Deployment options :)

Comment: Are you talking about "Local Git Repository"? if so, yes, you can always `git push` to Azure (it has a git server set up).

Comment: my problem was not being able to run `npm install` after deploy, but doing [it actual does it](https://s6.postimg.org/70e0t0ckv/screenshot_629.png)

Comment: ah I see what you did, adding a `git push` to your script, in that case you are all set